# MySQL: ERROR: failed to open file error2

Tags: mysql

Here are my steps:
1. use bank(my database);
2. SOURCE d:\Nitro\testing\SQL\Books_mysql\Cookbook\recipes\tables\cow.sql

When I tried to source for a particular .sql file, namely 'cow.sql', the following error is displayed:

> ERROR:
>   Failed to open file 'd:\Nitro\testing\SQL\Books_mysql\Cookbook\recipes\tables\cow.sql', error:2

content of "cow.sql":
    # Tables for online contruct-a-cow ordering scenario

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cow_order;
#@ _CREATE_COW_ORDER_TABLE_
CREATE TABLE cow_order
(
 id          INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 # cow color, figurine size, and accessory items
 color VARCHAR(20),
 size ENUM('small','medium','large') DEFAULT 'medium',
 accessories SET('cow bell','horns','nose ring','tail ribbon')
              DEFAULT 'cow bell,horns',
 # customer name, street, city, and state (abbreviation)
 cust_name   VARCHAR(40),
 cust_street VARCHAR(40),
 cust_city   VARCHAR(40),
 cust_state  CHAR(2),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
 #@ _CREATE_COW_ORDER_TABLE_

 # Add some orders to the table

 INSERT INTO cow_order (color, size, accessories,
                   cust_name, cust_street, cust_city, cust_state)
 VALUES
 ('Black & White','large','cow bell,nose ring',
 'Farmer Brown','123 Elm St.','Bald Knob','AR');

 SELECT * FROM cow_order\G

 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cow_color;
 #@ _CREATE_COW_COLOR_TABLE_
 CREATE TABLE cow_color (color CHAR(20));
 #@ _CREATE_COW_COLOR_TABLE_

 INSERT INTO cow_color (color)
 VALUES
 ('Black'),
 ('Brown'),
 ('Cream'),
 ('Black & White'),
 ('Red & White'),
 ('Red'),
 ('See-Through');

 SELECT * FROM cow_color;
```

Comment: can you post the contents of cow.sql?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be on Windows. Here you need to use forward slashes!

```
USE bank;

SOURCE D:/Nitro/testing/SQL/Books_mysql/Cookbook/recipes/tables/cow.sql;
```

Alternatively, you can use escaped back slashes:

```
SOURCE D:\\Nitro\\testing\\SQL\\Books_mysql\\Cookbook\\recipes\\tables\\cow.sql;
```

Comment: you must not put quotes around the path. And the file must exist in the given location and it must be readable by the mysql process.

Comment: I haven't used any quotes and this file is normally read by mysql process while using such command as: `mysql bank < d:\Nitro\testing\SQL\Books_mysql\Cookbook\recipes\tables\cow.sql`.

Comment: It's done...it's my fault...`d:\Nitro\тестирование\SQL\Books_mysql\Cookbook\recipes\tables\cow.sql` I use this code, but with russian word this command doesn't work properly.  When I use this `d:\Nitro\testing\SQL\Books_mysql\Cookbook\recipes\tables\cow.sql` and write russian word "тестирование" in English all has done correct. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I am glad it worked out. don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if your problem is fully solved.

Comment: Also, the source command MUST end in a semicolon, as shown above.

Comment: @Jeff I couldn't get a file I knew existed to load. I had to remove the semicolon to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, use forward slash (/) in in path, and provide full path.
For example:

`source C:/wamp64/bin/mariadb/mariadb10.4.10/bin/goblissl_oc.sql`

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if there are spaces in the path, just leave them as spaces. No need to escape them. At least that applies on a Mac.